# How to install only ssh in a gitlab CI build?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I want to create a `gitlab-ci` deploy stage that should upload a file via `ssh`.
My ubuntu image does not contain ssh, so I have to install it.

```
image: adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11
...

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - which ssh || (apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y ssh)
    ...
```

Problem: therefore I have to execute a full `apt-get install`, which will pull all latest updates for the image.

Result:

```
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dbus dmsetup file gir1.2-glib-2.0 libapparmor1 libargon2-0 libbsd0 libcap2
  libcryptsetup12 libdbus-1-3 libdevmapper1.02.1 libedit2
  [...]

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dbus dmsetup file gir1.2-glib-2.0 libapparmor1 libargon2-0 libbsd0 libcap2
  libcryptsetup12 libdbus-1-3 libdevmapper1.02.1 libedit2
  [...]
```

This feels kind of unnecessary for just getting a ssh client installed.
Question: is there a way to simply install only the `ssh` client without any os updates?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, `apt-get update` updates the list of packages to the newest ones, and `apt-get install ssh` installs *only* `ssh` and does not update the 'OS' (i guess you're using a Docker based runner) .

The extra packages that you see are dependencies that ssh requires. Alternatively, do check out the [gitlab ci docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/README.html#ssh-keys-when-using-the-docker-executor)

Comment: OK I was not aware those packages all belong to ssh.